# usage of not null and not empty in EL for Facelets page

Tags: jsf, facelets, el

In my backing bean if I have a list, then I can use

```
rendered="#{not empty name}" or rendered="#{not null name}"
```

right?
But if I have only instance variable(not a list), then can I use

```
rendered="#{not empty name}" ?
```

Comment: By the way, `#{not null name}` is invalid.

Comment: can you please tell me the uri library to be included for using 'not empty' feature ? thank you.